# Navigation in React Router v4 Native Not Changing Scenes

Tags: react-native, react-router

I'm using React Router for a React Native app. Not sure what I'm missing here but I install react-router-native and require the history package, and setup a couple methods that just push a new route onto the stack but nothing happens. I console.log('clicked'); to check that it's firing and it is so not sure what's wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Splash from './Splash';
import createHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory';

const history = createHistory();

class SplashContainer extends Component {
  goToLogin = () => {
    history.push('/Login');
  }
  goToRegister = () => {
    history.push('/SignUp');
  }
  render () {
    console.log(history)
    return (
      <Splash
        goToLogin={this.goToLogin}
        goToRegister={this.goToRegister}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SplashContainer;

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'native-base';
import { Link } from 'react-router-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Splash = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button light block onPress={props.goToLogin}>
        <Text>Login</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button dark block bordered style={{marginTop: 10}} onPress={props.goToRegister}>
        <Text>Register</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}

Splash.propTypes = {
  goToLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  goToRegister: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Splash;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your Router config, but your methods should be:

```
goToLogin = () => {
    const { history } = this.props
    history.push('/Login');
}
```

`history` will passed down via props of component inside Router's stack.